# How to get an HtmlElement value inside Frames/IFrames?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm using the `Winforms` `WebBrowser` control to collect the links of video clips from the site linked below.

[LINK](http://www.fuoriditesta.it/video-divertenti/marito-ubriaco-prende-la-moglie-in-braccio-ma-combina-un-disastro.html)

But, when I scroll element by element, I cannot find the `<video>` tag.

```
void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted_2(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        HtmlElementCollection pTags = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("video");
        int i = 1;
        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
        {

            if (link.Children[0].GetAttribute("className") == "vjs-poster")
            {
                try
                {

                    i++;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }   // Added by edit
}
```

Soon after using the

```
HtmlElementCollection pTags = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("video");
```

I already return 0

Do I need to call any ajax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Web page you linked contains [IFrames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlwindow.frames).
An `IFrame` contains its own [HtmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlwindow.document). As of now, you're parsing just the main Document container.
Thus, you need to parse the `HtmlElements` TAGs of some other `Frame`.
The Web Page Frames list is referenced by the [WebBrowser.Document.Window.Frames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlwindow.frames) property, which returns an [HtmlWindowCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlwindowcollection).
Each [HtmlWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlwindow) in the collection contains it own `HtmlDocument` object.

Instead of parsing the `Document` object property returned by a `WebBrowser`, we, most of the time, need to parse each `HtmlWindow.Document` in the `Frames` collection; unless, of course we already know that the required Elements are part of the main Document or another known `Frame`.

An example (related to the current task):

- Subscribe the [DocumentCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted?view=netframework-4.7.2) event of the WebBrowser Control/Class.
- Check the [WebBrowser.ReadyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.readystate?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to verify that a Document is loaded completely.

**Note:**
Remembering that a Web Page may be composed by multiple Documents contained in Frames/IFrames, we won't be surprised if the event is raised multiple times with a `ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete`.
Each Frame's `Document` will raise the event when the `WebBrowser` is done loading it.

- Parse the `HtmlDocument` of each Frame in the `Document.Window.Frames` collection, using the [Frame.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getelementsbytagname) method.
- Extract the `HtmlElements` `Attibute` using the [HtmlElement.GetAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute) method.

**Note:**
Since the `DocumentCompleted` event is raised multiple times, we need to verify that an `HtmlElement` Attribute value is not stored multiple times, too.
Here, I'm using a support custom Class that holds all the collected values along with the HashCode of each reference Link (here, relying on the default implementation of `GetHasCode()`).
Each time a Document is parsed, we check whether a value has already been stored, comparing its Hash.

- Stop the parsing when we verify that a duplicate Hash has been found: the Frame Document Elements have already been extracted.

**Note**:
While parsing the `HtmlWindowCollection`, it's inevitable to raise some specific Exceptions:

1. [UnauthorizedAccessException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.unauthorizedaccessexception): some Frames cannot be accessed.
2. [InvalidOperationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception): some Elements/Descendants cannot be accessed.

There's nothing we can do to avoid this: the Elements are not `null`, they simply throw these exceptions when we try to access **any** of their properties.
Here, I'm just catching and ignoring these specific Exceptions: we know we will eventually get them, we cannot avoid it, move on.

```
public class MovieLink
{
    public MovieLink() { }
    public int Hash { get; set; }
    public string VideoLink { get; set; }
    public string ImageLink { get; set; }
}

List<MovieLink> moviesLinks = new List<MovieLink>();

private void Browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var browser = sender as WebBrowser;
    if (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;

    var documentFrames = browser.Document.Window.Frames;
    foreach (HtmlWindow Frame in documentFrames) {
        try {
            var videoElement = Frame.Document.Body
                .GetElementsByTagName("VIDEO").OfType<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (videoElement != null) {
                string videoLink = videoElement.Children[0].GetAttribute("src");
                int hash = videoLink.GetHashCode();
                if (moviesLinks.Any(m => m.Hash == hash)) {
                    // Done parsing this URL: remove handler or whatever 
                    // else is planned to move to the next site/page
                    return;
                }

                string sourceImage = videoElement.GetAttribute("poster");
                moviesLinks.Add(new MovieLink() {
                    Hash = hash, VideoLink = videoLink, ImageLink = sourceImage
                });
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { } // Cannot be avoided: ignore
        catch (InvalidOperationException) { }   // Cannot be avoided: ignore
    }
}
```

Comment: I had not noticed the Iframe! Your explanation is perfect!