# Element "webBrowser". How to wait for the page to load?

Tags: c#, winforms

Document structure
"Form0" - Form
- - "panel2" - Panel
- - - "Frm5UC" - Custom item
- - - - "webBrowser1" - Browser

Application logic:
- go to the page in "webBrowser1";
- enter login;
- enter the password;
- click the "Login" button.

If I execute the logic through the code (this is the "Method_0 ()" method), the form does not have time to load in the "Authorization ()" method.
I get "webBrowser1.Document = null",
error "Object link does not indicate an object instance."

If I do everything through the interface, then everything works.

How to make the logic run programmatically?

```
private void Frm5UC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Visible = true;

            // *** TESTS ***
            Method_0();
        }



        #region *** TESTS ***
        public void Method_0()
        {
            Method_1();
            // Method_2();
        }

        public void  Method_1()
        {
            textBox2.Text = "_domain_com";
            textBox1.Text = @"domain_com/login/";

            button1.PerformClick();
        }

        public void Method_2() // Авторизация
        {
            Authorization();
        }
        #endregion *** TESTS ***


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);            
        }       

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Authorization();
        }       

        public void Authorization() // Авторизация
        {            
                foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
                {
                    if (he.GetAttribute("name") == "login[login]")
                    {
                        he.SetAttribute("value", "login798");
                    }
                }

            // Code "enter password"
            // Code "Press the button"
        }
```

**Update.**
I try to use the event "DocumentCompleted".
Added the variable "bool statusAuthorization;".

As a result:
- a page with fields for entering login / password opens;
and nothing else happens.
The code does not enter the login / password.

I try to do debugging.
Steps through the entire code.
No errors. Everything works, but the form with the browser does not open.

If I log in through the interface, then everything works.

```
bool statusAuthorization;

    private void Frm5UC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            webBrowser1.Visible = true;

            statusAuthorization = true; // !!! CHANGES

            // *** ТЕСТ ***
            Method_0();
    }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;

        if (statusAuthorization == true)
        {
            Authorization();
        }
    }

        #region *** TESTS ***
        public void Method_0()
        {
            Method_1();
            // Method_2();
        }

        public void  Method_1()
        {
            textBox2.Text = "_domain_com";
            textBox1.Text = @"domain_com/login/";

            button1.PerformClick();
        }

        public void Method_2() // Авторизация
        {
            Authorization();
        }
        #endregion *** TESTS ***


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);            
        }       

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Authorization();
        }       

        public void Authorization() // Авторизация
        {            
                foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
                {
                    if (he.GetAttribute("name") == "login[login]")
                    {
                        he.SetAttribute("value", "login798");
                    }
                }

            // Code "enter password"
            // Code "Press the button"

            statusAuthorization = false; // !!! CHANGES
        }
```

**Update**
Result: the form loads again and again.

```
private void Frm5UC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = "stop";
            webBrowser1.Visible = true;    

            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DocumentCompletedHandler);

            // *** ТЕСТ ***
              Method_1();
        }

     private void DocumentCompletedHandler(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                //Done!
                Authorization();
            }
```

Comment: You should probably use the WebBrowser's [DocumentCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted?view=netframework-4.7.2) event.

Comment: @LarsTech I tried to use it. Does not work. Could you tell me how to use it correctly? `private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)`

Comment: Post the code you wrote for the `DocumentCompleted` event.

Comment: @Jimi I don't understand how to organize the code.
What method to place there?
`Test2 ();`?

Comment: You probably want [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53213782/how-to-get-real-video-url-video-tag?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: @Jimi  I try to do this, but the code does not work exactly as I need `private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;

            Authorization();
        }`

Comment: Wouldn't there be two document completes?  First time loads the login page, and a second time for when a user successfully logs in?  You would have to know which page you are looking at.

Comment: @LarsTech   I ask you to excuse me, but still I do not understand how to arrange this event correctly.
All my attempts do not lead to the result.
Could you help or give a hint how to do this?

Comment: We don't see all your attempts.  The DocumentCompleted event is pretty simple.  When the document is finished loading, the event will run.  It's not clear what is null in your code when that event runs.

Comment: @LarsTech Updated question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool statusAuthorization;

private void Frm5UC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        webBrowser1.Visible = true;

        statusAuthorization = true; // !!! CHANGES

        // *** ТЕСТ ***

}

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;

    if (statusAuthorization == true && webBrowser1.Document != null)
    { Method_1();
        Authorization();
    }
}

    #region *** TESTS ***


    public void  Method_1()
    {
        textBox2.Text = "_domain_com";
        textBox1.Text = @"domain_com/login/";


    }






    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {Method_1();
        Authorization();
    }       

    public void Authorization() // Авторизация
    {            
            foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
            {
                if (he.GetAttribute("name") == "login[login]")
                {
                    he.SetAttribute("value", "login798");
                }
            }

        // Code "enter password"
        // Code "Press the button"

        statusAuthorization = false; // !!! CHANGES
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong in the question.
That's exactly what I did.
Do you propose to do so?
`public void Method_0 ()
    {
        Method_1 ();

    }
`
If yes, then I did.

Comment: @user9776818 yes and also you have  two functions `button1_Click`.

Comment: `you have two functions button1_Click` - сorrected.
Sorry, once again I will note that your answer duplicates my update and does not lead to a positive result.
I would appreciate if you advise something else.

Comment: Did you also remove `button1.PerformClick();`

Comment: if it is not working check the error and do  `if (webBrowser1.Document != null && webBrowser1.Document.Body != null) `

Comment: Did I understand you correctly? `private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (webBrowser1.Document != null && webBrowser1.Document.Body != null)
            {
                if (statusAuthorization == true)
                {
                    Authorization();
                }
            }`

Comment: As a result:
- a page with fields for entering login / password opens;
and nothing else happens.
The code does not enter the login / password.

I try to do debugging.
Steps through the entire code.
No errors. Everything works, but the form with the browser does not open.

Comment: See this:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/76b0feb2-6da6-468e-8956-92be1d7ac176/webbrowser-readystate-not-working?forum=winforms

Comment: Try to remove `Method_0();`

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Did you also remove from ` Method_1 ();` `button1.PerformClick();`

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand.
You ask a question or suggest removing `button1.PerformClick ();`

Comment: Try to remove it.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly? `public void  Method_1()
    {
        textBox2.Text = "_domain_com";
        textBox1.Text = @"domain_com/login/";

webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
            // button1.PerformClick();
    }`

Comment: I do not see in your code a transition to a page for entering a login and password.

Comment: Or do I not understand something?

Comment: @ There is no code  for the password you have to add it `// Code "enter password"
        // Code "Press the button"`

Comment: Your problem was about `webBrowser1.Document = null, error`