# WebBrowser Document null in DocumentCompleted

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am blocked in using the WebBrowser document for `MouseDown` event Handler.

Designer:

```
this.webBrowser.TabIndex = 4;
this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
```

Form class:

```
private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser.Document.MouseDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(webBrowser_MouseDown);
}

private void webBrowser_MouseDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
}
```

In the code above, when loading the first URL selected, it will call `DocumentCompleted`.
According to documentation, the WebBrowser's document should be complete when this event is raised.

But I meet an error because `webBrowser.Document` is null and I didn't find any explanation.

Is there a way to retrieve the loaded Document in `DocumentCompleted`?

Comment: Read the notes here: [Getting mouse click coordinates in a WebBrowser Document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54232729/7444103) and here: [How to get an HtmlElement value inside Frames/IFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218064/7444103).

Comment: Thank you Jimi for these links. That's pretty much what I found online. However, after I red these, I checked in my code what was the value of ReadyState. Apparently, the ReadyState is kept Uninitialized in case the link is a local URI, and not http address. Is there a way to initialise the document in case of local address (C://)?

Comment: The document source is not important. It could be a remote Https resource, a localhost http resource of a local file. The `DocumentCompleted` event is raised indifferently. Its `ReadyState` is set according to the state of the Document load process. If you still have some problems, post the code you're using now.

Comment: Cannot reproduce error you get