# IE freeze while handling MSHTML.Document mouse events in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I need to capture the attributes of clicked elements in my application IE browser. 
All works fine and I am able to capture the attributes but the IE window gets unresponsive. i.e. if I click in the textbox the cursor will not be shown and mouse scroll will not work.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports mshtml
Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer()
    Dim WithEvents Doc As New mshtml.HTMLDocument
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Empty As Object = 0
        Dim URL As Object = "file://D:/AtestWeb/index_Calls_popup.htm"

        ' override BeforeNavigate2 event
        'IE.BeforeNavigate2 = New SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(AddressOf e1.OnBeforeNavigate2)

        IE.Visible = True
        IE.Navigate(URL)

        'IE.Navigate2(URL, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty)

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    End Sub
    Private Sub IE_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, ByRef URL As Object) Handles IE.DocumentComplete
        Doc = IE.Document
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub Doc_onmouseup() Handles Doc.onmouseup
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Doc.activeElement.innerText)
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I remove mouse event everything works fine.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can also use the standard WebBrowser control and do something like this: [Download Image under the Mouse pointer via WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56169490/7444103). Note that the clicked HtmlElement is determined using the `[WebBrowser].Document.GetElementFromPoint()` method. Then get the `[HtmlElement].InnerText` (or whatever). Also, read (in any case) the notes about the `DocumentComplete(d)` event and the IFrames part.

Comment: `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` is **never** an acceptable way to deal with UI threading issues.

Comment: Yes, this issue is not there when using WebBrowser. But I need to do this using IE since it's an upgrade from legacy application.