# MouseClick event handler doesn't work in ChromiumWebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium, mouselistener, cefsharp

On other objects like the Forms itself MouseClick event works but when it comes to ChromiumWebBrowser the event handler simply doesn't listen any mouse clicks.

The browser is in a tab page. I tried to listen mouse clicks from there but that also didn't work.

```
private void ChromeBrowser_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     Log("Click");
}
```

Designer.cs:

```
// 
// chromeBrowser
// 
this.chromeBrowser.ActivateBrowserOnCreation = false;
this.chromeBrowser.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.chromeBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
this.chromeBrowser.Name = "chromeBrowser";
this.chromeBrowser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1003, 539);
this.chromeBrowser.TabIndex = 0;
this.chromeBrowser.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.ChromeBrowser_MouseClick);
//
```

Comment: You usually need to handle click event of html elements. What's the problem which you are trying to solve?

Comment: [Getting mouse click coordinates in a WebBrowser Document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54232729/7444103). Of course you need to use a supported Element type.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I need to get coordinates in chrome browser in order to simulate some key strokes and click events which depends on those coordinates.

Comment: So I think you can follow the approach which is shared in the linked post.

Comment: Just one point, the event can be handled easier. You don't need to add/remove the handler by every navigation. Just one time registration would be enough, after navigating to `"about:blank"` (for `WebBrower` control or such similar address for CefSharp), get the document object and subscribe to its click event. Also to simulate click later, you probably need `Cursor.Position`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Unfortunately CefSharp doesn't expose DOM elements

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. I've always used WebBrowser control.

Comment: A workaround could be trying to handle `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` using a message filter or a native window. Take a look at this issue https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1098

Comment: CefSharp uses Javascript to access the DOM. You can apply the same concept using its methods. See the CefSharp FAQ about this: [CefSharp - Frequently asked questions](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions) and in [CefSharp General Usage](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage), see [Javascript integration](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#javascript-integration), specifically [Part #3 - Expose .NET classes to Javascript](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript).