# Vb.Net web browser Not Working to Some Website

Tags: vb.net, browser

I need some coding for vb.NET web Browser I paste this URL but not login and not signup ply solved my problem I have used the below code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://freebitco.in/")
End Sub
```

Comment: Take the class (`WebBrowserAdvancedFetures`) shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57615713/7444103). It provides two methods: `ActivateWBAdvancedFeatures` and `DeactivateWBAdvancedFeatures`. Call the former in the Form's constructor (`Public Sub New()`, as shown there) and the latter in the `Form.FormClosed` event (or when the application exits). That's all.

Comment: dear i want to work the following site when i click the button then the website will opened complete but there is one problem i cant login or signup to website plz tell me the solution

Comment: Please solved my problem