# This Website Not login in Web Browser vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need code for web browser (vb.net) I want to login to a website in web browser but it's not logging in.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://freebitco.in/")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Username, Password As String
    Username = "myemail@gmail.com"
    Password = "my password"
    '   WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("fileupload").InvokeMember("click")

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btc_address").SetAttribute("value", Username)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_form_password").SetAttribute("value", Password)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_button").InvokeMember("click")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Is not the first time here is talked abut this site (here another: [Vb.Net web browser Not Working to Some Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480365/vb-net-web-browser-not-working-to-some-website)  same author but now deleted from this account) with similar question on WebBrowser. 
Is bad habit to do advertising on StackOverflow.
Saying that:
Your code needs to be inside another event gesture which is:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

            AddHandler Button2.Click, Sub()
                                          Dim Username, Password As String
                                          Username = "myemail@gmail.com"
                                          Password = "my password"
                                          '   WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("fileupload").InvokeMember("click")

                                          WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btc_address").SetAttribute("value", Username)
                                          WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_form_password").SetAttribute("value", Password)

                                          WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_button").InvokeMember("click")
                                      End Sub

End Sub
```

Instead of your code.

Comment: What is this can i run my code in Web browser Documents send the example code

Comment: I update my answer, try this updated code instead of your code

Comment: dear this coding not working until the page not login or signup i want login

Comment: what is the button click coding

Comment: @khair-ali is the Button2