# VB.NET - Instagram website is not opening on the web browser control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

It is just me or everyone is not able to open Instagram on Web Browser control ?

It is getting stuck on the splash screen. I'm using latest version of in Web browser which is - 11.

It was all working good yesterday but it is not working now.

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.ToString & BrowserKeyPath,
                                          Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName & ".exe",
                                          11000,
                                          Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
```

I checked the version and browser agent, and everything is latest. Also scripting errors are suppressed.

```
InstagramBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
InstagramBrowser.ObjectForScripting = True
```

Here is the screenshot where you can see it is stuck.

Screenshot Link: https://prnt.sc/qu56ru

What could be the issue ?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the two methods shown here: [Some Elements missing while downloading from HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57615713/7444103) to update the Registry keys. Verify in your Project's Properties, before anything else, that the `Compile` configuration is set to `Any CPU` and that the `Prefer 32-bit` option is not selected.

Comment: Yes it is set to ```Any CPU``` only!

Comment: Well, you forgot to mention what the `Prefer 32-bit` option is set to, if you have tested those methods and, in this case, what is the result.

Comment: The result remains same. :/

Comment: Instagram works without any problem with the standard WebBrowser control. If it doesn't work for you, then you didn't implement that code correctly. Post what you have done (your actual code).

Comment: Hello @Nihas, I am experiencing almost the identical problem. It was working just fine yesterday and now it does not . I tried emulation stuff but no luck. Have you solved your problem?