# How to send data to a specific site via vb.net

Tags: vb.net

### vb.net

**Hi**, I was using the **webbrowser** to enter data from a **textbox** to a specific website

But now I am facing a problem as the site I want to enter data into does not support the web browser

I would like in a way that I can send data to a site without the need of a **webbrowser**

**For example**, ***Twitter***  does not support the web browser. When I want to create a browser that creates an account on Twitter, the site gives me an error message that the browser is not supported.

Comment: Apply this: [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/7444103) and you'll have Twitter on your WebBrowser control. A VB.Net implementation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57615713/7444103) (see the `WebBrowserAdvancedFetures` class and the code that calls its methods). You may also want to use the WebBrowser overload that accepts the `AdditionalHeaders` argument (you can specify a User-Agent header, try with the FireFox ~48 header, for example)

Comment: The Edge header also works. Try it: `"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.74 Safari/537.36 Edg/79.0.309.43"`

Comment: You'll probably want to abandon the WebBrowser entirely and send/receive requests directly to Twitter.  You can intercept those with something like Fiddler2.  I'd recommend using their API https://developer.twitter.com/en but they won't want you creating new accounts automatically.  If you're looking to mass-create account it's probably breaking their ToS and you'd have to factor how you'd authenticate their verification emails as well.

Comment: How i can use this in my project https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589227/some-elements-missing-while-downloading-from-httpwebrequest/57615713#57615713