# VB.NET - WebClient - How to make it act more like a real browser?

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I am using a vb.net webclient and am having difficulty connecting to certain sites and retrieving content. It seems to be that certain sites recognise this is a webclient and not a real browser.

I am using a cookie aware version of the webclient, but the sites in question come back with a 500 error, i'm certain they are being blocked by the web servers as using a normal browser to the same URL will work fine.

I've added user-agent headers and also tried a few others (cache policy, pragma, encoding) but none seem to help.

Does anybody know of a way to make the webclient act more like a real browser?

Thanks

Comment: Start applying this: [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/7444103), expand with this: [Web browser control emulation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626667/7444103). You may want to add `FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING` and, eventually, `FEATURE_WEBOC_DOCUMENT_ZOOM` + `FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE`. Note that these Registry entries not always already exist, so you have to create them first. A VB.Net implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57615713/7444103)