# How to fill a WebForm and click the submit Button with a WebBrowser control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control, form-submit

How can I click this `SUBMIT` button using a WebBrowser control?

[image]

I've tried with:

```
For Each divSect As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
    If divSect.OuterHtml.Contains("Accedi") Then
        For Each elem As HtmlElement In divSect.Children
            If elem.GetAttribute("type") = "button" Then
                elem.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: On a side, this type of thing you probably better off splitting the logic in the click event off into it's own method.  The you can call that method directly from your code behind and or click event handler without the need to worry about UI implementations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample procedure to perform a WebForm LogIn using a WebBrowser control.

▶ **Note**: I suggest to activate the WebBrowser Emulation Advanced Features beforehand, in case its need. Read [a description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57615713/7444103) (see the `WebBrowserAdvancedFetures` class):
(The `FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING` Key may not exist, so it may be necessary to create it first)

- Subscribe to the [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted) event before navigating to an Address

  - As describe in [How to get an HtmlElement value inside Frames/IFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218064/7444103), the Document may be actually composed of more than one Frame/IFrame (the latter, quite common). If that's the case, you need to handle the `DocumentCompleted` more than once, since each Frame/IFrame has its own Document
- When the event is raised, check whether the [WebBrowser.ReadyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.readystate) is [WebBrowserReadyState.Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowserreadystate): return if its not (we don't want to handle partial documents).
- When the current Document is complete find a Form with a specific ID or class name: that's the Login Form we want to fill in.
- When the Form is found, parse its Document and to select the `INPUT` elements that require a value.
- If all elements are found and their values has been set, find the `SUBMIT` Button and call its [InvokeMember()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.invokemember) method, specifying the `click` handler to complete the procedure and activate the Form `POST` method.
- When the Button is clicked, the WebBrowser is redirected to a landing page, so we remove the Handler of the `DocumentCompleted` event: we're done here, handling this event is no longer need.

▶ Set **`[WebBrowser].ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True`** in the Form's Designer.

```
Private Sub btnNavigate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNavigate.Click
    AddHandler webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Browser_DocumentCompleted
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://SomeAddress.com")
End Sub

Private Sub Browser_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim browser = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)
    If browser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then Return

    ' Select a Form with a specific className
    Dim form = browser.Document.Forms.OfType(Of HtmlElement).FirstOrDefault(Function(frm) frm.GetAttribute("className").StartsWith("form-login"))

    ' Not found at this point, try later
    If form Is Nothing Then Return

    ' Select the element by ID or by className or whatever
    Dim userId = form.Document.GetElementById("[The UserId Input's ID]")
    ' Same for other input elements
    Dim userPwd = form.Document.GetElementById("[The Password Input's ID]")
    If userId Is Nothing OrElse userPwd Is Nothing Then Return

    ' Set the value of both Input elements. Note that a validation procedure 
    ' may require that you set both the Value and the InnerText
    userId.SetAttribute("value", "[The User LogIn ID]")
    'userId.InnerText = "[The User LogIn ID]"
    userPwd.SetAttribute("value", "[The User LogIn Password]")
    'userPwd.InnerText = "[The User LogIn Password]"

    ' Filter (fail-safe) the SUBMIT button by className, since - here - it has no ID
    Dim submit = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button").OfType(Of HtmlElement).
        FirstOrDefault(Function(elm) elm.GetAttribute("type").
            Equals("submit") AndAlso elm.GetAttribute("className").Contains("bt-label"))

    ' The SUBMIT Button was found: click it. Also remove the handler: we're done here
    ' The WebBrowser is redirected to a landing page, this event is no longer needed
    If submit IsNot Nothing Then
        RemoveHandler browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Browser_DocumentCompleted
        submit.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sensational. It might be the most serious log in via WebBrowser someone can find online.