# How to get all Elements from Body in VB.Net Like as <Section>?

Tags: html, vb.net, element, document-body, tagname

view page source Without section:
[image]
Inspect Elements With section:
[image]

I have problem to get all elements from website by **VB.Net**.

for example : Instagram website

```
<body class style>
  <div id="react-root">    
    <section class="_9eogI E3X2T"><div></div><main class="SCxLW  o64aR " role="main"> . . . </section> . . . </div> . . . </body>
```

How can I get **Section** element ?

I try with this code: (for example)

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.instagram.com/")
```

and in WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted:

```
Dim elms As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml
```

but when to try get all them form **WebBrowser1**, Returned Body with no True Elements ?

section not receive by OuterHtml !?

I using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: where's the code you tried? please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `dim divElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("react-root") 
dim sectionElement = divElement.Children.OfType(Of HtmlElement)().FirstOrDefault(function(elm) elm.GetAttribute("className").Equals("_9eogI E3X2T"))`

Comment: Thanks
but not working for me
(div id="react-root") is loaded in WebBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml, but "section" not loaded

Comment: Read the notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218064/7444103) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64668045/7444103)