# WebBrowser - An error has occurred in the script on this page

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control

When I use the Webbrowser Control I keep on getting this message. How do you fix it?

Also, the websites I go on with this have trouble rendering due to this problem. What do I do?

Side note: I want to change the contents of a textbox on a website:

https://zh.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=%E9%AB%98%E9%BA%97%E5%8F%B2/%E5%8D%B7%E4%B8%89%E5%8D%81%E4%B8%80&action=edit.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: 1) Add `ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true` and set the emulation mode to IE11 (take the `WebBrowserAdvancedFetures` class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57615713/7444103) and call its `ActivateWBAdvancedFeatures` method as shown) 2) Use [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) instead.

Comment: Thank you my friend! I'm new to Documents and The Microsoft Documents do NOT, AT THE VERY LEAST, help me at all in getting used to this. Is there like a video tutorial I can find on youtube or something that helps me with this? Because I CANNOT find ANY videos on this matter. That being said, I do not understand many of the things in your linked post!

Comment: Also, I've seen and copied your custom made class into my Visual Basic Code. WHAT is RegistryKey? I keep seeing it and it gives me a lot of errors. Not only that, I can't find it in the Microsoft documents! What do I do?

Comment: You cannot find [RegistryKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey) in the Docs? -- When you have Keywords that the IDE cannot recognize, just put the caret inside that Keyword and press `ALT+ENTER`: Visual Studio will suggest what missing assemblies to add to the Project References and what `Imports` to add to the current class. Not just suggest, it will actually add them for you.

Comment: I was typing registryKey in the search engine and it returned not the thing I wanted.
That's because I'm using Visual Basic probably

Comment: Next time, in a search engine, type `MSDN Docs registryKey` :) Better be specific.

Comment: I KNOW WHAT HAPPENED I FORGOT TO IMPORT THE TWO THINGS!!!!!!!!

Comment: By the way, are there any tutorials that I can use to learn about all of this? Microsoft Docs is very very unhelpful in that matter.