# WebBrowser href.invokemember error in VisualBasic

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to envoke a text url with no id, I am able to envoke it via the href.innertext just fine but for the program i am creating the innertext will not be completely known before hand. Therefore i am using keywords that i know will be included in the text.

I have tried to assign the href.innertext to a string and try "if string.contains("blah blah")" but i get an error.

```
        Dim HTML As HtmlDocument

        HTML = WebBrowser1.Document
        For Each href In HTML.Links
            item = href.innerText
            If item.Contains("Blah Blah") Then
                href.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
```

the code above returns

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

item was Nothing.
```

Comment: That's not the way to work with the html document provided by a WebBrowser. Read the notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218064/7444103) and use the `DocumentCompleted` event as described.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on this code and when it hits use Debug > Windows > Threads.  Verify it runs on the Main thread and is triggered by the DocumentCompleted event, it can't work correctly on a worker thread.  It can also be caused by embedded Javascript altering the page content, nothing much you can about it but waiting long enough with a Timer until it is done.