# How to wait untill geckofx browser load in c#?

Tags: c#, browser, geckofx

Im using geckofx browser for loading web page and search some data on webpage.

my code is

```
public void Navigate(string url){
    //.....some code
    browser.Navigate(url);

    var errorTost = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("class-name");
  //....some more code
}
```

issue im facing is i can not check `errorTost` is exists or not because browser is not completely loaded.

then i have use `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted` and `webBrowser_Navigating`
to find whether browser is completely loaded.

new modified code is as bellow

```
var isBrowserLoading = false; // class variable

public void Navigate(string url){
    //.....some code
    browser.Navigate(url);

    while(isBrowserLoading ){}

    var errorTost = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("class-name");
  //....some more code
}
 private void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        isBrowserLoading = false;
    }

    private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        isBrowserLoading = true;
    }
```

but `isBrowserLoading` is never get updated.
Can any one help me on this?!

Thanks.

Comment: You got true and false backwards. isBrowserLoading should be initially set to TRUE and then when complete set to FALSE.

Comment: Remove this: `while(isBrowserLoading ){}`. Move `var errorTost = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("class-name");` in the `DocumentCompleted` event (that's when you know the `DomDocument` can be parsed). Btw, is this a WinForms Project? Another (event-driven) GUI Framework?

Comment: @Jimi yes winforms project.
when i move extraction part to event it will run when browser initially loads.
i can use flag to identify it but is there any good way to do this?

Comment: @jdweng no it freezing the ui browser is not loading!

Comment: Do you mean, you want to parse a specific document, from a specific URI? Are you navigating to a different site when the Control is loaded? You can just add a flag (a `bool` field), setting it to `true` when you want to start parsing the `DOM`. `return` if set to `false`. Or check the current URI before parsing.

Comment: @Jimi can i wait still browser loads?
becouse i have 10 urls in a for loop, loop running  fast than browser loads

Comment: Ah, all right. You have the loopy-problem. Solved by not using a loop :) Add the URLs to a List, `Navigate` to the first. When you're done parsing the first URL, call `Navigate()` again from the `DocumentCompleted` event (or the parsing procedure activated by the `DocumentCompleted` event). It can always be tricky if a Document contains more than one Frame (each IFrames contains a Document, for example. Each IFrame can raise the `DocumentCompleted` event).

Comment: This is something similar, using the standard WebBrowser control: [How to get an HtmlElement value inside Frames/IFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218064/7444103).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201254/discussion-between-roshan-and-jimi).