# Capture frames from browser

Tags: c#, browser

I would like to write a c# script that captures images from a browser every second until I press stop. Does anyone have any ideas of how I can do this? Or if there are some existing examples?

Comment: `captures images from a browser every second until I press stop` = can you clarify, please?

Comment: I want to Take a print screen every second (but only for a given window frame, not the whole screen). I want to capture images in order to record a workflow. I am looking for ideas of how I can write this in code

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218064/10216583) post.