# How to set the Style of a HtmlElement at the Mouse position when a Key is pressed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a `TABLE` Element in the current Document of a WebBrowser control.
I want to be able to color a Cell when my cursor is on it, when I press the **`A`** Key

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        htmlDocument1 = WebBrowser1.Document
        AddHandler htmlDocument1.MouseOver, AddressOf Me.gettd
End Sub

Public Sub gettd(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementEventArgs)
    Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection
    theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        e.ToElement.Style = "background-color: orange;"
    Next
End Sub
```

Setting `KeyPreview = True`:

```
Public Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
   If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
   ...
   end if
End Sub
```

How else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes are required:

- The `DocumentCompleted` event can be used to add handlers to other events, but you have to remember that this event is raised multiple times **per URI navigated**: you're adding a multitude of handlers to the `MouseOver` event.
  It's simpler, in this case, to add a handler when the URI has been [Navigated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated) and remove it when we're [Navigating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating) to another.
  Also, read the notes here: [How to get an HtmlElement value inside Frames/IFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218064/7444103)
- Instead of parsing the whole collection of Elements in the Document, we can simply use the [Document.GetElementFromPoint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementfrompoint) method, passing the [e.ClientMousePosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelementeventargs.clientmouseposition) value provided by the `MouseOver` or `MouseMove` events as the current Point position.
- The Form's KeyDown event cannot be used to trap keys pressed - even with [KeyPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview) set to `True` - when other controls capture the input. You can get that key press overriding the Form's [ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey), since it's called when messages are pre-processed.
- Always check for `null` before accessing a [HtmlElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement) or its properties. E.g., string properties never initialized are `null` (`Nothing`), not `String.Empty`.

Add this code to a Form, then navigate to a Html Page:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("[Some URI]")
```

I've added a toggle function, to set the current Cell's Style to a `background-color` value when `Keys.A` is pressed and set it back when it's pressed again. Here, hard-coded to `white`, but you can add some logic to save the previous style, if required.

```
Public Class FormBrowser
    Private trackedElement As HtmlElement = Nothing
    Private elementColorOrange As String = "background-color: orange;"
    Private elementColorWhite As String = "background-color: white;"

    Private Sub webBrowser1_Navigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles webBrowser1.Navigating
        If webBrowser1.Document Is Nothing Then Return
        RemoveHandler webBrowser1.Document.MouseOver, AddressOf OnBrowserMouseOver
    End Sub

    Private Sub webBrowser1_Navigated(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) Handles webBrowser1.Navigated
        AddHandler webBrowser1.Document.MouseOver, AddressOf OnBrowserMouseOver
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        If keyData = Keys.A Then
            If trackedElement IsNot Nothing AndAlso trackedElement.TagName = "TD" Then
                Dim currentStyle As String = trackedElement.Style & ""
                trackedElement.Style = If(currentStyle.Contains(elementColorOrange), elementColorWhite, elementColorOrange)
                Return True
            End If
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function
End Class

Private Sub OnBrowserMouseOver(sender As Object, e As HtmlElementEventArgs)
    Dim doc = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser).Document
    If doc Is Nothing Then Return
    trackedElement = doc.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition)
    txtElmName.Text = trackedElement?.OuterHtml
    txtElmValue.Text = trackedElement?.InnerHtml
End Sub
```

This is how it works:

[image: WebBrowser Track Mouse Position]