# Suppress/Intercept Alt+Left/Alt+Right in WinForms WebBrowser Control

Tags: .net, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts, webbrowser-control, intercept

We have a WinForms app with the [WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=net-5.0) control on a form (currently compiling it for the classic .NET Framework 4.7.2). We need to suppress or intercept the Alt+Left and Alt+Right keyboard combinations when this WebBrowser control has the input focus to implement our own history navigation. We tried several methods including overwriting of the [Control.ProcessCmdKey()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey) for the control or the whole form, but this does not help. How to do what we need in .NET Framework in C# or VB.NET?

Comment: You can override the Form's `ProcessCmdKey`, then add the condition `if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.Left)) { // do something }` -- See the example here: [How to set the Style of a HtmlElement at the Mouse position when a Key is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61318665/7444103) -- You didn't specify a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you cannot subscribe to the WebBrowser KeyDown, KeyUp or KeyPress events without getting a runtime error you can subscribe to the [WebBrowser.PreviewKeyDown Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=net-5.0) to detect the <kbd>Alt-Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Alt-RightArrow</kbd> key combinations.

If you set the [PreviewKeyDownEventArgs.IsInputKey Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs.isinputkey?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_PreviewKeyDownEventArgs_IsInputKey) to true in the event handler, the WebBrowser Control will not interpret the combination as the WebBrowser.GoBack/WebBrowser.GoFoward commands.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.PreviewKeyDown
  If e.KeyData = (Keys.Left Or Keys.Alt) OrElse e.KeyData = (Keys.Right Or Keys.Alt) Then
    ' setting IsInputKey = true prevents the Browser for processing 
    ' Alt-Left Arrow and Alt-Right Arrow as history navigation
    e.IsInputKey = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that helps!! It was enough to override `OnPreviewKeyDown()` and do our custom actions for Alt+Left/Right before calling `base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e)` even without setting `e.IsInputKey` to True. I must also mention that the [WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.webbrowsershortcutsenabled) property for our descendant of the WebBrowser control is set to False.