# get a detail from html document with webbrowser control of vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, htmlelements

I'm a newbee in handling html document with vb.net webbrowser

i have an the html document,  in that some objects are selectable, i'm  able to load this html document in vb.net webbrowser control of vb.net, is there in possible way to get a selected object information in vb.net

html document used is available in bellow link...
[HTML File link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O0rTFqvWbxGGg3PBgjcdZhIuuearAGo7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: [How to set the Style of a HtmlElement at the Mouse position when a Key is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61318665/7444103)

Comment: Anyway, you probably want to replace your WebBrowser Control with [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/). It's simple to inject JavaScript and send messages to the Document and receive notifications from event listeners.

Comment: I don't see the webview2 control in my vb toolbox, I'm i missing something?

Comment: You have to add it using NuGet Package Manager.