# Extract data from a website in winforms c#

Tags: c#, html, winforms

i want to extract some data from a website. f.e. (https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/drucken/512261146932016/Annas-Rouladen-mit-Seidenkloessen.html). The text on the left side an the ingredients table on the right.

i tried several ways like with a webclient and regex the parts but the problem was here that if the table has more than one list like in my example i cant split them.

i also tried it with an htmldocument and get the elements but the 
elements doesnt have an id; only a class.

so is there any way to get these two thing out of the website? 
im pretty new too html and that kind of stuff..

Comment: That's a very simple layout. The class name is an HtmlElement's `Attribute`. The Attribute name is `className` (note the camel-case). You can use the standard WebBrowser control to navigate to that page. Use the `DocumentCompleted` event as shown here: [How to get an HtmlElement value inside Frames/IFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218064/7444103). See the notes about IFrames, too.

Comment: Hey im an absolute newbie to this. Could you  specify your solution a little bit?

Comment: It's all explained in the answer I linked (`DocumentCompleted` and `Attributes` usage included).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using some sort of web scraping library like https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/webscraper/ or Selenium. Doing so, you'll be able to target HTML elements and css classes (to extract the data).