# [VB.NET]How to parse this html?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, html-parsing, webbrowser-control, webclient

I've just found a textarea I couldn't parse as I can't see the text on html.

The example page is [Online editable notepad](https://pad.riseup.net/p/iMQNvq6JP9l7Fh0RX9qW-keep)

How would you parse the textarea in vb.net?
either with webbrowser or webclient.
thanks

Comment: The Text is inside a Document of an IFrame that is part of the main Document. The `ID` of the `BODY` element is `innerdocbody`. The text itself is presented using `SPAN` elements in `DIV` containers, with `className = "ace-line"` (`className` is the name of the element Attribute). See [How to get an HtmlElement value inside Frames/IFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218064/7444103)

Comment: Thanks! Right because the text is presented using span elements in Div containers, should I parse every div? I've tried with Id and classname attribute but I wasnt able to parse it. That s a bit far from my understanding. Thanks

Comment: You need to extract all `DIV` elements which have `className` (or just `class`, if you're using HtmlAgilityPack) equals to `ace-line`, get the `value` or `InnerText` of the `SPAN` child element and combine all these text parts to recreate the full Text. Note that you cannot use the standard WebBrowser Control for this, IE11 is not supported.

Comment: Eventho I know how to display IE11 in webbrowser, I guess I have to skip this project as It goes far from my capacities. Thanks !

Comment: Hi Jimi, would you mind to explain me better with a code answer for better understanding?