# Winform Webbrowser control Document.All.GetElementsByName not finding element

Tags: javascript, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, winforms-to-web

I am unable to find the desired element when I use

```
 HtmlElementCollection elements = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("username");
```

The count is always 0. However, it is able to find the element when I iterate the **`elements`** using for loop like this:

```
 foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
        {
            if (element.Name == "username")
            {
                try
                {

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Why is this? I would prefer to get the desired elements in one line instead of writing foreach loops for all of them.

Comment: How did you check the count?

Comment: I checked the count property of the elements variable.

Comment: Check the `length` property instead.

Comment: If you instead write: `var element = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("username").OfType<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault();`, is `element` null? -- Where / when are you running this code? Are you sure the Document(s) is (are) loaded completely? Note that it's (are) loaded asynchronously (the Main Document can contain more sub-Documents).

Comment: @Teemu Does `HtmlElementCollection` have a `Length` Property?

Comment: @Jimi - Yes. It still shows element as null

Comment: @ Jimi - Going by what you said about the document loading, if I use if(element != null) condition, it eventually finds it and goes inside the if condition.

Comment: Read the notes here: [How to get an HtmlElement value inside Frames/IFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218064/7444103)