# Get href of a button through web browser control

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to get the href of a button using the control Web Browser.
The html is:

```
<a download="" href="https://x638jxfnvmcxbaxcskqsdadskdqnfwexc.shikisha.shiksha/f2xcqrz1wxf13dssdalkgrdjkgdklfjdsaklkcxmsacxzcdfsvsdcqwdjkkvfmdskicmsdascmamzcassmdamcxscxzcsacasvfdssacxzcsdxvsaqswcxzvbededvvb.php?nqusjmslpeprtmdsjkhghewojicwe0guhifkjbh2qqqhstexrsfiwhvfmmoorewioujgbhuiovshdkjwvcjhfdbwehjkvkjhsdnvmwouipfdwxjwsfiwhvfhlmj=yyhnlsoahifiztdsjkhghewojicwe0guhifkjbh2qqqhscscvsfiwhvffbbsrewioujgbhuiovshdkjwvcjhfdbwehjkvkjhsdnvmwouipfdryansfiwhvfmwdn222811prciwnbztwy5&amp;pxhotisnweqwlkdsjkhghewojicwe0guhifkjbh2qqqhsotjpsfiwhvfnshnrewioujgbhuiovshdkjwvcjhfdbwehjkvkjhsdnvmwouipfdnpsesfiwhvfoczq=yloyeevwdfcbpkdsjkhghewojicwe0guhifkjbh2qqqhszjdssfiwhvfeyczrewioujgbhuiovshdkjwvcjhfdbwehjkvkjhsdnvmwouipfdozixsfiwhvfhcimfslzpcikfrvnqldsjkhghewojicwe0guhifkjbh2qqqhsptjesfiwhvfmzsrrewioujgbhuiovshdkjwvcjhfdbwehjkvkjhsdnvmwouipfdyskesfiwhvfcchh&amp;fkdsadxcwaqcscasxcsacxsaxazxcvsdvdslssafdsvx=174147325&amp;dkjfsjksdadsdvcxxcvswscxrewsdf=sdx2&amp;sdwreggllslsdxvc&amp;sadklxcklkvb=qwrdcbkklsdxk&amp;jiijlks=lz9fSJUhlRoBL8M8qh4Ido&amp;uijdsdkdfkgfdsd=85652262237b1335ca34.14415852&amp;lkfdsfxc=lz9fSJUhlRoBL8M8qh4Ido&amp;nqusjmslpeprtmdsjkhghewojicwe0guhifkjbh2qqqhstexrsfiwhvfmmoorewioujgbhuiovshdkjwvcjhfdbwehjkvkjhsdnvmwouipfdwxjwsfiwhvfhlmj=yyhnlsoahifiztdsjkhghewojicwe0guhifkjbh2qqqhscscvsfiwhvffbbsrewioujgbhuiovshdkjwvcjhfdbwehjkvkjhsdnvmwouipfdryansfiwhvfmwdn222811prciwnbztwy5&amp;pxhotisnweqwlkdsjkhghewojicwe0guhifkjbh2qqqhsotjpsfiwhvfnshnrewioujgbhuiovshdkjwvcjhfdbwehjkvkjhsdnvmwouipfdnpsesfiwhvfoczq=yloyeevwdfcbpkdsjkhghewojicwe0guhifkjbh2qqqhszjdssfiwhvfeyczrewioujgbhuiovshdkjwvcjhfdbwehjkvkjhsdnvmwouipfdozixsfiwhvfhcimfslzpcikfrvnqldsjkhghewojicwe0guhifkjbh2qqqhsptjesfiwhvfmzsrrewioujgbhuiovshdkjwvcjhfdbwehjkvkjhsdnvmwouipfdyskesfiwhvfcchh"><button id="myImageId44" type="button" class="download2 download2dahover"><font color="#F08080">Download MP3 (Bitrate: 320 kbps | 7.28 MB | 00:03:10)</font></button></a>
```

The code I'm trying inside the event Document Completed of the Web Browser control is:

```
Dim HtmlCollec As HtmlElementCollection
        HtmlCollec = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
        For Each iElement As HtmlElement In HtmlCollec
            If iElement.GetAttribute("id").Equals("myImageId44") Then
                RichTextBox1.Text = iElement.ToString
                           End If
        Next
```

but Im getting as output:

> System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement

How can I get it? Thanks

Comment: `iElement` is the HTML element. You need its OuterHtml. -- You can just call `GetElementById()`, since you know the ID of this Element.

Comment: The outerhtml contains the link that I don't have yet.. outerHTML: `"<a download=\"\" href=\"looooong link\"><button id=\"myImageId44\" type=\"button\" class=\"download2 download2dahover\"><font color=\"#F08080\">Download MP3 (Bitrate: 320 kbps | 7.28 MB | 00:03:10)</font></button></a>"`

`Dim HtmlCollec As HtmlElementCollection
        HtmlCollec = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByid("myImageId44")
        For Each iElement As HtmlElement In HtmlCollec
            If iElement.OuterHtml Then
                RichTextBox1.Text = iElement.ToString
            End If
        Next`

Comment: what should I use instead?

Comment: I've tried also with
 `Dim Element As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myImageId44")
        If Element.OuterHtml.Contains(">Download MP3 (Bitrate:") Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = Element.GetAttribute("value")

        End If`
but it doesn't return any output

Comment: You can try `Element.OuterHtml.GetAttribute("href")`

Comment: which codes of mine you are referring to?

Comment: `dim element = [WebBrowser].Document.GetElementById("myImageId44") if element isnot nothing andalso element.Document.Links.Count > 0 then dim link = element.Document.Links(0).GetAttribute("href") end if` -- Or get the OuterHtml and parse the `href` part. Or use HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: @Jimi I'm getting "identifier expected" on [0]

Comment: Right, I wrote it partially in C#. Fixed.

Comment: @jimi that code returns a link but that's not the link I'm expected.
I've also tried getting part of the outer html and parse the href part with:
`Dim element = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myImageId44")
        If element.OuterHtml.Contains(">Download MP3 (Bitrate:") Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = element.GetAttribute("value")
        End If`
but I'm not getting any output

Comment: What Link did you expect? How many Links are there in the `HtmlElement.Links` collection? I based that snippet on what you posted here. That's `https://x638jxfnvmcxbaxc [...]`

Comment: I'm not that sure, now for example I re tried your code and it doesn't give me any link.. 
I'm working on this website [link](https://ytmp3eu.com/en45/) just using a simple link like [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJUhlRoBL8M)  and getting the link of the button Download

Comment: @Jimi the HtmlElement.Links has just a single link, this one [link]("https://ytmp3eu.com/hu29/")

Comment: Well, then there's a good change that Web Site, as many others do, uses IFrames to updated dynamic content. So you read just the Links of the main Document. Read the notes here: [How to get an HtmlElement value inside Frames/IFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218064/7444103). -- Store the `OuterHtml` when you get one or more Links from the HtmlElement you're inspecting. Possibly using a dedicated class object / collections as shown in that example.

Comment: Thanks Jimi I'll try to translate it to vb.net. Does the `GetElementById("myImageId44")`  still be valid for that code?

Comment: @Jimi  `Dim href = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myImageId44").Parent.GetAttribute("href")` this works ;)